# How to create WCF service that accepts MTOM encoded request

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, mtom

I need to create WCF service that is able to accept following **request** that is sent from java based web application:

```
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:83d3b2a6-5437-4366-bfb1-6f7c8b49add5"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="application/soap+xml; action=\"urn:test:test1:ResponseInputMessage\""
Headers: {Accept=[*/*]}
Payload: --uuid:83d3b2a6-5437-4366-bfb1-6f7c8b49add5
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="application/soap+xml; action=\"urn:test:test1:ResponseInputMessage\""
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><some_xml></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:83d3b2a6-5437-4366-bfb1-6f7c8b49add5--
```

All I have is XSD files with request and response types. I generated classes and created basic service.

**Service contract**:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IResponseService
{
    [OperationContract]
    AcknowledgementType ResponseInputMessage(RegistryResponseType registryResponse);
}
```

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpMtomBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MySvc.ResponseService">
    <endpoint address="ResponseService.svc" contract="MySvc.IResponseService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpMtomBinding"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I get an inbound message to my service it fails with 404.

I tried to create .net client based on wsdl of my new service to compare requests, however Fiddler showed me 4 requests that were slightly different from original request:

Request 1:

```
POST http://localhost/ResponseService.svc HTTP/1.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=1";start-info="application/soap+xml"
Host: localhost 
Content-Length: 1468
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive


--uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=1
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"

<s:Envelope>...</s:Envelope>
--uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=1--
```

Request 2:

```
POST http://localhost/ResponseService.svc HTTP/1.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=2";start-info="application/soap+xml"
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 1393
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


--uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=2
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"

<s:Envelope>...</s:Envelope>
--uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=2--
```

Request 3:

```
POST http://localhost/ResponseService.svc HTTP/1.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=3";start-info="application/soap+xml"
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 6705
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


--uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=3
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"

<s:Envelope>...</s:Envelope>
--uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=3
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/636522286300409121>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<BINARY DATA>
--uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=3--
```

Request 4:

```
POST http://localhost/ResponseService.svc HTTP/1.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=4";start-info="application/soap+xml"
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPoy345YauwrpHkI3FNjB7gLEAAAAApHotH5ktEkaKGEpmm9Yap6yU6ZXr2SJLlqP656qr/dsACQAA
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 6565
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


--uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=4
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="application/soap+xml"

<s:Envelope>...</s:Envelope>
--uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=4
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/636522286300539469>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<BINARY DATA>
--uuid:cc8ae94d-3397-4384-8460-738cf53f967b+id=4--
```

Can somebody please explain how requests are mapped to operation contracts? What I am missing in my service definition? In original request there is at least `action=\"urn:test:test1:ResponseInputMessage\""`.

When you create a client you can generate everything automatically from wsdl is there reverse approach to generate service based on request?

Any help/docs would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would declare a method like
`[OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "POST"] public Message ReadPost(Stream stream) {......}` 
and use a MultiPart content parser (I think it is available at nuget "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client")

Comment: @L.B thanks for your suggestion. I will use it as a last resort, however I would like to implement this properly. Since WCF supports MTOM there should be a way to handle deserialisation in WCF framework.